# Google Calendar API 'start-min' parameter not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

This is my code:

```
oauth_yaml = YAML.load_file('google-api.yaml')
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.client_id = oauth_yaml["client_id"]
client.authorization.client_secret = oauth_yaml["client_secret"]
client.authorization.scope = oauth_yaml["scope"]
client.authorization.refresh_token = @rtoken
client.authorization.access_token = @token

if client.authorization.refresh_token && client.authorization.expired?
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
end

service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => service.events.list,
  :parameters => {'calendarId' => @calendar, 'start-min' => Time.now.xmlschema},
  :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
)

@parsed = JSON.parse(result.data.to_json)
```

I'm getting all events regardless of if the 'start-min' parameter is included or not.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct parameter is actually timeMin, not start-min.